# Модульный проект на Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, maven, модули

Привет!
Есть следующая задача: создать прототип сайта с реализацией модулей. Наприрмер:
1) модуль, который отображает простую веб странице
2) модуль, который отображает картинки на веб странице.

Настройки веб страницы хранятся в таблице page (Айди, путь, название страницы, контент html), а в таблице imgage хранятся ссылки на картикни и страница на которой их отображать (Айди, Айди страницы, урл картинки).

Надо создать такой проект, чтобы подложил допустим jar файл куда-то - и страницы отображаются, убрал - не отображаются. Положил модуль отображения картинок - на страницах начали отображаться картинки, убрал - перестали отображаться.

Как это реализовать?

Я умею вытаскивать данные из базы данных, умею создавать MVC проект без модулей. Но с модулями не могу понять.

Как это праивльно делать? И как потом запускать такой проект с возможностью добавлять и убирать jar файлы?